# How to fix deprecated Zend_Rest Client in Magento 2?

Tags: php, rest, magento2

A module I'm maintaining is not working on Magento 2.3 since Magento  apparently deprecated Class 'Zend_Rest_Client' . I don't see any replacement Client listed in their documentation, so I'm a bit confused on which class I should be extending now.

This is my class on line 5:
`class Client extends \Zend_Rest_Client`

This is the error thrown in Magento 2.3:

`( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Rest_Client' not found in /m23/app/code/Maurisource/Module/Model/Rest/Client.php on line 5`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Also, there is a [Magento stack-exchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) for Magento-related questions.